# extract csv content from an xml tag

Tags: xslt, xpath

i have a source xml as below

```
<rest-adapter-response>
  <metadata>
    <status>success</status>
  </metadata>
  <status-line>
    <code>200</code>
    <reason>OK</reason>
  </status-line>
  <header-lines>
    <Cache-Control>private, max-age=0</Cache-Control>
    <Transfer-Encoding>chunked</Transfer-Encoding>
    <Content-Type>application/octet-stream</Content-Type>
    <Expires>Thu, 25 Apr 2019 08:51:55 GMT</Expires>
    <Last-Modified>Fri, 10 May 2019 08:51:55 GMT</Last-Modified>
    <Server>Microsoft-IIS/10.0</Server>
    <X-SharePointHealthScore>1</X-SharePointHealthScore>
    <X-SP-SERVERSTATE>ReadOnly=0</X-SP-SERVERSTATE>
    <DATASERVICEVERSION>3.0</DATASERVICEVERSION>
    <X-Download-Options>noopen</X-Download-Options>
    <Content-Disposition>attachment</Content-Disposition>
    <SPClientServiceRequestDuration>224</SPClientServiceRequestDuration>
    <X-AspNet-Version>4.0.30319</X-AspNet-Version>
    <SPRequestGuid>de31db9e-70cb-8000-7fba-6c3e85d9c810</SPRequestGuid>
    <request-id>de31db9e-70cb-8000-7fba-6c3e85d9c810</request-id>
    <MS-CV>ntsx3stwAIB/umw+hdnIEA.0</MS-CV>
    <Strict-Transport-Security>max-age=31536000</Strict-Transport-Security>
    <X-FRAME-OPTIONS>SAMEORIGIN</X-FRAME-OPTIONS>
    <X-Powered-By>ASP.NET</X-Powered-By>
    <MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices>16.0.0.8824</MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices>
    <X-Content-Type-Options>nosniff</X-Content-Type-Options>
    <X-MS-InvokeApp>1; RequireReadOnly</X-MS-InvokeApp>
    <P3P>CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"</P3P>
    <Date>Fri, 10 May 2019 08:51:55 GMT</Date>
  </header-lines>
  <message-body>
    <non-xml-data-response>COA,COA Acct Desc,Acct Prefix,Revaluation Acct,Mapping Changes - Additions( A )  Deletions ( D ) Changes ( C ),MJE,OIM Recon,Comments for difference:10000274,"Citibank, Operating, USD, 31165975",1000,10009999,A,,X,10000374,"Citibank, Clearing, USD, 31165975",1000,10009999,A,,X,10006604,"HSBC, Operating, SAR, SA0345000000003179660002",1000,10009999,A,,X,10006605,"Citibank, Operating, ZAR, 0202099009",1000,10009999,A,,X,123,,,456,,,,</non-xml-data-response>
  </message-body>
</rest-adapter-response>
```

above XML is the response of a share point web service which tried to read a csv file and gave a response like this. as you can see in the above response xml , csv data did come but inside one xmltag called `<message-body>` , and also lost the new line after every row format!!

now i need to recreate the csv !!. and the worst part is , in the tool where i receive this format i have capability to write xslt and xml ! no hosting language code or libraries could be used. 
also only xslt 1.0.

there is a question like this 
[question on creating csv from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182127/parsing-string-inside-xml-element-into-csv-using-xslt) , but this is bit different from my requirement . am just learning xslt and xpath , can any one help me in this ?

below is the requested output : 
[click here to view the csv format](https://textuploader.com/1d9jl)

Comment: Do you have a specific ruleset when to make linebreaks? It would be useful to know what you need the csv for. Maybe we can find another solution without recreating the csv. E.g. it may be enough to access every comma separated value by itself. This could be done by a for-each over tokenize(.//non-xml-data-response, ',')

Comment: yea i get your point, my requirement is to pass the entire csv file in this case . so we need  not concentrate on the csv values induvidually. 
how ever the larger problem for me (by now you would have guessed) is to retrieve a csv file from the share point via web services.

[link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262992/retrieve-csv-file-data-using-sharepoint-webservices-with-foramt)

this link  can explain  the larger problem. **but for now as i said i need the whole csv file**

Comment: Huuuh. I do not think that there is a ruleset which we can use to produce linebreaks which would work on every csv document. Is the csv document consistent in its structure and is that all the data it can contain? If yes we could build a ruleset like: Put a linebreak in front of the first big number. After that we can put a linebreak after 7 commas which are not in quotes. Would this work for you?

Comment: i think we need not worry about the "big number" , every seven commas , if we are able to insert a line break  then we are good. that will create all the rows including header wont it ?

Comment: How would you approach this task if doing it manually? Unless you have some way of determining how many separate values are in each row, this problem is insolvable.

Comment: Ugh so you just want a table out of it? Thats kind of simple to group every 7 elements. Should I write the code to transform the csv into an xml where the first 7 entries are the nodenames and every further entry gets into the corresponding tag like: <COA>21312</COA><COA Acct Desc>"some text" </><Revalua...>...</>...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one makes the assumption that the header row is terminated by a colon and that there are 7 values in each data row*, then it's possible to use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/rest-adapter-response">
    <xsl:variable name="csv" select="message-body/non-xml-data-response" />
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($csv, ':')" />
    <xsl:text>:&#10;</xsl:text> 
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:call-template name="restore-csv">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($csv, ':')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="restore-csv">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, ',')">
            <xsl:variable name="value">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with($text, '&quot;')">
                        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
                        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, ',')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable> 
            <!-- output -->         
            <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$i mod 7 = 0">
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="restore-csv">
                <xsl:with-param name="text">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="starts-with($text, '&quot;')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;,')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text, ',')"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

**Result**

```
COA,COA Acct Desc,Acct Prefix,Revaluation Acct,Mapping Changes - Additions( A )  Deletions ( D ) Changes ( C ),MJE,OIM Recon,Comments for difference:
10000274,"Citibank, Operating, USD, 31165975",1000,10009999,A,,X
10000374,"Citibank, Clearing, USD, 31165975",1000,10009999,A,,X
10006604,"HSBC, Operating, SAR, SA0345000000003179660002",1000,10009999,A,,X
10006605,"Citibank, Operating, ZAR, 0202099009",1000,10009999,A,,X
123,,,456,,,
```

---

This may need more work to handle possible escaped double-quotes within quoted values.

---

--
(*) The strange thing here is that there are 8 values in the header row, but only 7 in the data rows.

Comment: Great effort and guessing skills!

Comment: i just got a chance to verify the result pls wait. i will verify and close this thread

Comment: the transformation is working fine. but my tool accepts any result which is inside a n xml tag. so i inculded a tag `<result>`  just after this `<xsl:template match="/rest-adapter-response">`  . also in cluded a `</result>` just after ` </xsl:call-template>` but in the result am not still getting this result tag . my result should be something like below 

`<result>
csv content .......
</result>`

Comment: Try changing the output method to `xml`.